# How to auto start an application in openwrt?

Tags: shell, openwrt, autostart

I have created a shell with necessary functions such as
    start()
    stop()
    restart()

But my file is not getting started at boot time.

I have used **update-rc.d** command in "ubuntu" to add this file to the list of autostart applications. And it was successfully started at boot time.

But in "openwrt" I have seen an **enable** function. Anyone aware of how to use this enable function or is there any similar command like **update-rc.d** in "openwrt"

I had some reference here : http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/initscripts

Comment: This question is not about the C language, remove the `c` tag.

Comment: my mistake... Its removed..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

/etc/init.d/  - directory will by automaticly readed and searching for boot function or START STOP.
Starts at boot time.

```
boot() {
        echo boot
        # commands to run on boot
}
```

START-Position then to start

STOP-Position then to stop

```
START=10 
STOP=15

start() {        
        echo start
        # commands to launch application
}                 

stop() {          
        echo stop
        # commands to kill application 
}
```

**EDITED:**

In /etc/rc.common directory files are compiled whoes going to start on boot.

Enable your function: /etc/init.d/your_script.sh enable

Here you will find more information about booting http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/process.boot

Comment: Thanks for the response,

But content in the link provided with the question saying the same thing.
I tried it.. But not working

Answer (score 29):

1. Make sure the first line of your script reads:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
   ```
2. Copy your script to the `/etc/init.d/` directory
3. Make sure the execute bit is on

   ```
   chmod +x /etc/init.d/<your script>
   ```
4. Enable your script

   ```
   /etc/init.d/<your script> enable
   ```

   Your script should now have a symlink in `/etc/rc.d/`

   ```
   ls -lh /etc/rc.d | grep <your script>
   ```
5. Confirm your init script is enabled:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/<your script> enabled && echo on
   ```

   If this command returns `on`, then you're all set. If this command doesn't return anything, then your script isn't enabled. Here's an example of a script that's enabled:

   ```
   root@OpenWrt:~# /etc/init.d/system enabled && echo on
   on
   ```

I've tested these steps on OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05 but it should work on earlier versions. Good luck!

Comment: This is gold. I've come back to this answer several times now.  :)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to run your command only at system start (just after boot):
edit **/etc/rc.local** that is your file.

By default it contains just comments (Designated Driver, but this was the case in some earlier versions also):

```
# Put your custom commands here that should be executed once
# the system init finished. By default this file does nothing.
```

You can add commands here.

My example:

```
# Put your custom commands here that should be executed once
# the system init finished. By default this file does nothing.

if grep -q '/dev/sdb2' /proc/swaps ; then swapoff /dev/sda2 ; fi
comgt -s /etc/config/init-script.comgt
```