# Daemonize nodejs app on mediatek 7688

Tags: node.js, linux, openwrt

I'm using the Mediatek 7688 board running OpenWRT linux to create an IoT device. I have written the app in NodeJS and want it to be executed anytime the board boots up.

I have tried the solution given [here] ([How to auto start an application in openwrt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340659/how-to-auto-start-an-application-in-openwrt/33708161#33708161)) while this works but the board seems to be unable to complete the boot process (the NodeJS app doesn't exit). I have also tried the pm2 npm module but am running into issues with diskspace during installation.

Is there a way to reduce the "installed" size of the pm2 module? Or maybe a way to fire up the NodeJS scripts upon startup without using the module.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was only using the pm2 module to ensure that:

1. The program started at bootup
2. The program was restarted in case it crashed

To accomplish the first part and since my program was a node.js program, I made it into an executable file by adding `#!/bin/sh env node` as the first line in the file. Must ensure that the line ends in a LF line ending and not CRLF as in case of windows systems. Once done, I granted execute permission to the .js file by calling `chmod a+x myfile.js`.

I then created an init script in the /etc/init.d folder and enabled that script - as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340659/how-to-auto-start-an-application-in-openwrt/33708161#33708161)

Now to ensure that the process restarted automatically in case it ever crashed, I a "cron script", like so and saved it a restart.sh in the root folder:

```
#bin/sh
if pgrep -f myfile.js > dev/null
then
   #process is already running - do nothing
else
   /etc/init.d/myprocess start
fi
```

And finally setup a `crontab -e` with `* * * * * ~/restart.sh` so that the restart.sh gets executed every minute to ensure that the process is running.